# Convertir un observable a un array local

Tags: array, angular, typescript, observable

Guardar el valor del array observable en un array local y poder usarlo para añadir más usuarios, ya que, el servidor remoto http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users no permite editar los datos, es de prueba.

**user.component.ts**

```
users: User[];

getUsers() {
  return this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

No sé si voy mal encaminado, pero la idea que tengo sería obtener los datos de la base de datos remota sólo cuando la variable del array local esté vacío y a partir de ahí, manipular los datos desde dicha variable local.

```
getUsers() {
  if (this.users == null) {
    this.users = this.userService.getUsers()
                                 .subscribe(users => this.users = users as User[]);
  }
  return this.users;
}
```

Comment: Quieres guardar lo que te devuelve el json en local para luego poder editar, añadir y eliminar?

Comment: Efectivamente, coger los datos que me da la base de datos remota y guardarlos en un array local y poder hacer un push en caso de querer añadir un nuevo usuario. Porque la propia base de datos no soporta un crud, simplemente es para consultar.

Comment: Tu código hace eso ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: El código que muestro funciona, pero recoge los datos de la base de datos remota siempre. Entonces, ahora quiero añadir una nueva funcionalidad que sería agregar un nuevo usuario, pero de forma predeterminada no puedo hacerlo con la base de datos remota, por ello, quiero guardar el json que obtengo de usuarios en una variable local de array. Espero que se entienda.

Comment: Como dice @Pablo, tu código ya lo hace, es decir, en la variable "this.users" ya tienes el array con los usuarios recuperados de esa BD remota. Sin embargo, piensa que ese array y esa base de datos no están conectadas, y que si haces un `push()` (añadir) o cualquier otro tipo de operación, no se verá reflejado. También ten en cuenta que si actualizas o refrescas la página, al estar trabajando con datos en memoria, ese array no será persistente y perderás los datos que hayas añadido, modificado o borrado

Comment: Voy a intentar explicarme lo más claro posible. Lo único que quiero conocer es como 'conectar' los datos obtenidos de la basa de datos remota con el array 'this.users' y que se guarden, al haber conseguido eso, podría añadir un nuevo usuario y si navego, no se perderá como me está ocurriendo ahora.

Comment: Creo que no vas a poder hacer eso, pq es una base de datos remota que imagino que no permitirá guardar datos, ya que si almacena los datos de todo el mundo se volvería una base de datos inmensa. Si lo que quieres es simular una app real necesitarás implementar un backend propio o utilizar una herramienta similar a un json-server [documentación](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Comment: Por eso quiero guardar los datos en una variable local, porque sé que no se puede guardar en la base de datos remota, lo que no sé es como guardar los datos obtenidos del JSON en una variable array local, con tal de seguir manipulando los datos a partir de ese array.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido: ¿quieres simular que insertas los datos en la base de datos? Se puede hacer que esos datos se guarden en el navegador por tiempo indefinido, pero no afectará a ningún otro usuario

Comment: Eso es, coger prestados los datos de la base de datos. Estoy haciendo pruebas, por ahora quiero conseguir eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres almacenar los datos que te vienen del servidor remoto para luego modificarlas, la mejor manera es almacenarlo en el localstorage y a partir de ahi ya puedes editar, añadir o eliminar.

Ejemplo:

```
  getUsers() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') == undefined) {
      return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
            map(resultados => {

                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(resultados));

              return resultados;
            }));
    }
    else {
      return Observable.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    }
  }
```

Por lo que si quieres eliminar un usuario simplemente accedes al localstorage, borras el user que quieres y lo vuelves a guardar.
Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. Voy a probarlo y te cuento.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione